# Hibernate query accessing previous version of data object?

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I have a piece of code using hibernate which behaves unexpectedly; after trying many different debugging strategies, I am wondering if my understanding of Hibernate sessions / mapped object updates is incorrect. Here is the simplified scenario:

I have a mapped object (MO) which is defined with an id (long) and a date (date/time).
There is a main routine which runs every 60 seconds which checks for any MOs that need to be processed, based on a date/time. The main routine runs in a single thread. Here is the  pseudocode:

```
main () 
// open session
// get current date/time
// query all mapped objects where date/time field < current date/time
// for each mapped object which matches {
//   updateObject (session, current date/time, mapped object)
// }
// flush session
// close session

updateObject( Session s, Date currentTime, MappedObject mo ) 
// changes to mo object 
// add 1 day to currentTime and update date/time field in mo
// transaction begin
// update mo object
// transaction committed
```

Not shown: session factory initialization, exception handling routines

The session factory is configured with max connection pool size of 20 (c3p0).
Default settings are being used for any caching.

**The problem**

The query is returning MOs whose date values are in the future (i.e date/time field **>** current date/time). According to the object watch, the value of the date/time field in the MO is the old, previous value (not the recalculated, updated value), which forces the query to pick it up and execute the updateObject routine.

I assume that the update was successful by verifying the update by monitoring the DB directly; also, none of the transaction exceptions are triggered according to the logs.

This problem occurs intermittently - sometime, it happens several times a day, other times it does not happen at all.

**Platform details**

Hibernate version: 3.3.2.GA

c3p0 version: 0.9.1

JRE version: 1.6.0_16

**My thoughts**

My first thought was a coding error, but it does not appear to be the base. I am wondering if somehow an old version of the object is cached in one of the Session objects in the connection pool, and for some reason, it gets picked up from time-to-time.

I am worried about the larger implications if there is a problem with the updates.

I am using an older version of Hibernate at this time - migrating to a new version could be challenging, but I want to see if I have misunderstood something before going that route.

Any suggestions or directions to results would be most appreciated - thanks in advance!

**Update**

Moving to Apache DBCP seems to have resolved the problem. Will update if the problem is observed again.

Comment: The session cache is going to be cleared out whenever you close the session (which it appears you are doing) regardless of whether you are using connection pools or not.  This would seem far more likely to be related to a second-level cache or a query cache.  Both of those are not on by default, have you configured your application to use a 2nd level cache or query cache?

Comment: @pace I took a look at the documentation for 2nd level cache (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache) - it's not something which I enabled. Ditto with the query cache option (hibernate.cache.use_query_cache). It's weird because I suspected caching, but by all indications, it should be off. Given the intermittent nature, I'm wondering if it might have been a bug in an older version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you can try...

1) Set the following Hibernate property to turn statement caching off:-

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
```

If that doesn't work...

2) Instead of using C3P0, try out [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) to see if you have the same issue. It should an easy swap out.

Comment: I believe that caching is off by default - I don't have that configuration option at all. I'll give DBCP a try - I hear that it's getting more maintenance than c3p0 nowadays. Thanks.